# Error in Matlab code using rand function

Tags: matlab, random

I have been using the following matlab code to generate random numbers,

```
rand('state',0);
n=100;
m=300;
A=rand(m,n);
b=A*ones(n,1)/2;
c=-rand(n,1);
```

However, it keeps giving me the message "Error in ESE605_Homework_4 (line 1)
rand('state',0)'"I have tried to evaluate the problem, and it says I should switch to using the "rng" function because newer versions of Matlab discourage use of "rand". However, upon switching to the rng, function I am still having issues. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? Your code works for me, no complaints.

Comment: Please paste the full error message.

Comment: Please put also the code for `rng` into your question. This is the recommended way to use it. And read the tag descriptions before using unrelated tags!

Answer (score 0):

From [Matlab documnetaion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

for 'state' option you should use rng function instead of rand